# ¿como hago que se cree una notificacion automaticamente despues de crear un continido con django-notifications-hq?

Tags: python, django

quiero hacer un sistema de notificación en django, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Con la lib django-notifications-hq quiero hacer que se cree una notificación automáticamente cuando registre un proyecto indicando a los usuarios que le asignaron un proyecto.

Quiero que la notificación muestre un párrafo sencillo como "El usuario X te añadió al proyecto X el dia X como ROLES".

Mi modelo:
mi modelo registra permite registrar un proyecto y asignárselo a un usuario con sus respectivos roles (responsible, accountable, consulted, informed)

```
class Project(models.Model):

DURATION_UNIT_LIST = [
    (1, _("Hour")),
    (2, _("Day")),
    (3, _("Week")),
    (4, _("Month")),
]
STATUS_LIST = [
    (1, _("On hold")),
    (2, _("In progress")),
    (3, _("Completed")),
    (4, _("At risk")),
    (5, _("Behind time")),
]
code = models.CharField(_("Code"), max_length=50, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=50, unique=True,)
scope = models.TextField(_("Scope"))
attachment_files = models.FileField(
    _("Attachment Files"),
    upload_to="attachment_files/",
    max_length=2621440,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)
responsible = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name="projects_fk_00",
    verbose_name=_("Responsible"),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
)
accountable = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name="projects_fk_01",
    verbose_name=_("Accountable"),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
)
consulted = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name="projects_fk_02",
    verbose_name=_("Consulted"),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
)
informed = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name="projects_fk_03",
    verbose_name=_("Informed"),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
)
business_goals = models.ManyToManyField(
    BusinessGoal,
    verbose_name=_("Business Goal"),
    blank=True,
    help_text=_(
        "The business goals this project belongs to. A project will get all permissions "
        "granted to each of their business goals."
    ),
    related_name="projects_fk_04",
    related_query_name="project",
)
duration_type = models.IntegerField(
    _("Duration Type"), choices=DURATION_UNIT_LIST, default=1
)
duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Duration"), default=1)
start_date = models.DateField(_("Start Date"), default=now)
predecessor = models.ForeignKey(
    "self",
    related_name="projects_fk_05",
    verbose_name=_("Predecessor"),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)
status = models.IntegerField(_("Status"), choices=STATUS_LIST, default=1)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name="projects_fk_05",
    verbose_name=_("Created by"),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(_("Created on"), auto_now_add=True)
updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name="projects_fk_06",
    verbose_name=_("Updated by"),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(_("Updated on"), auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = "projects"
    verbose_name = _("Project")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Projects")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("update", kwargs={"project_pk": self.pk})
```

Me gustaría que me indicaran como hacerlo, ya que estoy empezando en Django